# Cloud firestore - adding object to an array of objects

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am using Cloud Firestore (not Realtime Database). I have a document of user details containing an array (cards) of user credit cards, i.e. Card objects. A card object is structured as follows:

```
{
    address: "123"
    number: "456643634634634"
    postcode: "hshshs"
}
```

The document is defined as follows:

```
userDocument : AngularFirestoreDocument<User>;
this.userDocument = this.afs.collection('users').doc(`${this.userId}`);
```

When a user adds a new card, I call the following function:

```
addCard(card: Card){
    this.userDocument.update({
        cards : firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(card)
    });
}
```

However, I get errors before even saving the document saying:

```
[ts]
Type 'FieldValue' is not assignable to type 'Card[]'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type 'FieldValue'. [2322]
user.model.ts(15, 5): The expected type comes from property 'cards' which is declared here on type 'Partial<User>'
```

Not sure how to use `arrayUnion` to add an element to an array in Cloud Firestore correctly. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Perhaps AngularFire requires you to only pass objects of type Card to update(), based on the typing of userDocument?

Comment: the object I am passing to update is of type Card, hence the input parameter in the addCard function, which is `card: Card`, which is of type Card. Is that what you mean?